# Pointer dereferencing in a variable and in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, variables, cs50

I am somewhat confused on pointers. I have two of them in the following code I'm using and they are working but I'm not 100% sure why they are working.

The first is

```
char *note = "A7";
```

The second is

```
char *octFreq[15] = 
       {"1","55","2","110","3","220","4","440","5","880","6","1760","7","3520"};
```

They both get to the value of each though I had to use `*` before the array and not before the single variable.  I am able to get the value of note by just using note though cannot do this for `octFreq`.

Here is the line of code I'm a little confused by and all of the code immediately follows.

```
    if(note[1] == *octFreq[x]){//WHY DO I HAVE TO DEREFERENCE octFreq and not note????
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){ //Notes are in this order C D E F G A B

    char *note = "A7";
    //char freq;
    int semiUpDown = 0;

    char *octFreq[15] = {"1","55","2","110","3","220","4","440","5","880","6","1760","7","3520"};

    //int noteIndex[7] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    if(note[1] == '#'){
        semiUpDown = 1;
        //Up one semitone or multipled by 2^1/12
    }else if(note[1] == 'b'){
        semiUpDown = -1;
        //Down one semitone or divide by 2^1/12
    }

    if(semiUpDown == 0){//This means no flat or sharp

        if(note[0] != 'B' || note[0] != 'b'){//Check the first letter is CDEFGA

            if(note[0] == 'A' || note[0] == 'a'){//Check to see if it's the baseline

                for(int x = 0; x < 13; x++){

                    //printf("%s\n\n", noteA[x]);

                    if(note[1] == *octFreq[x]){//WHY DO I HAVE TO DEREFERENCE octFreq and not note????
                        //freq = *octFreq[x+1];
                        // printf("Found it:  %s\n\n", noteA[x]);
                        printf("This is the frequency:  %s\n\n", octFreq[x+1]);
                    }
                }    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `note[1]`?

Comment: I wanted to check the second character of the string

Comment: None of this code makes sense. Why wouldn't you just have an array of **integers**, having the frequency of `A` in each octave?

Comment: `note` is a pointer to char. So `note[1]` is a single character. `octFreq` is an array of pointers to char. So `octFreq[x]` is a pointer, and `*octFreq[x]` is a single char. You could also write `*octFreq[x]` as `octFreq[x][0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

char *note = "A7" means that you have declared a pointer to a char array. Therefore you can access its elements by note[0] etc. like any other array.

char *octFreq[15] means that you declared a pointer to an array of char pointers.

octFreq[15] would reach to the char pointer at the index 15.
*octFreq[15] would reach to the char pointed by the char pointer at the index 15.

Comment: THIS MAKES SO MUCH SENSE!!!  THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR RESPONSE!!!!!!

Comment: @ndjustin20 Add to your epiphany that `note` is a *pointer to a string literal* (created in read-only memory) and that `octFreq` is an *array or pointers to multiple string literals* (also created in read-only memory)

Comment: Thank you David I appreciate the advice!!!

Answer (score 1):

`if(note[1] == *octFreq[x])` is only comparing a single character so it works for `A7` but won't work for `A110`.  There you need to use strcmp which uses `char *` to compare entire strings.  Something like this;

```
if (0 == strcmp(&note[1], octFreq[x]))
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  I purposely didn't use strcmp() as I knew I only had to check digits 1...7 and I can just use == to compare two chars

Comment: @ndjustin20 but in your octFreq you have `1`, `110`, and `1760` so comparing just the first character doesn't seem reliable.

Comment: It never even dawned on me!!! Looking at the frequencies and octaves I just got lucky.  THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR POINTING THIS OUT!!!

Answer (score 0):

The index operator (`[]`) is an automatic dereference of a specific integer amount from the base pointer value.

So, to explain. A pointer is really just a variable that holds a memory location. This memory location is a specific integer value (i.e. `4000`, `9320`, etc.). You can add, subtract, multiply, divide, etc., this variable to get a new memory location that points to a valid value of the type the pointer points to (in this case, a `char`).

Your first pointer variable, `note`, could be defined as such:

```
char* note = new char[3];
*(note + 0) = 'A';
*(note + 1) = 'F';
*(note + 2) = '\0'; \\all character arrays have an implicit null-terminator
```

Each character can be then referenced as: `note[x]`, where 0 <= x <= 2. `note[x]` can also be read as `*(note + x)`.

Comment: Thank you for responding I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

char* note = "A7"; // here you define **note** - array of chars ('A', '7', '\0'). When you access note[1], you get the second symbol ('7').

char* octFreq[15] = {"1","55","2","110","3","220","4","440","5","880","6","1760","7","3520"}; // here you define **octFreq** - array of arrays of char. There are 15 arrays, were every has type **char***. So when you access octFreq[3], you getting the fourth element of **array of arrays of char** and it is **array of chars** ("110" in this example). Then you apply * to this **array of chars** and you get the first element of this array (it is bold one here -> "**1**10"), because the pointer to **array of chars** (char*) actually points to it's first element.

Comment: Thank you for responding I appreciate it.